# time sort on questions

Tags: support, questions, sorting

Not for any real purpose I was trying to see some really old posts in the asp.net tag, to see what was asked etc

So I changed the sort word from newest to oldest and it did nothing. Now I perfectly understand that the sort might not be that hackable/implemented (i'm just guessing that it may have worked)...but I wasn't expecting it to still display the newest questions...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net?sort=oldest&pagesize=50

**edit** Or as I've just discovered the last item you picked that was legit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that "oldest" is somehow mapping to "newest", but rather than you've specified an invalid sort order, causing it to automatically show you the *default* sorting order. That just happens to be "newest".

You can test the theory by omitting the sort identifier altogether:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net?pagesize=50

It's still sorted by "newest".

Comment: You're right...except that it's the "last" tab you previously selected...clicking your link a few hours later for example took me to the "unanswered" tab...